# @async remotecall_fetch on GPU

Tags: julia

I have been interested about GPU programming since a couple of months ago and now I am trying to learn how to do it in Julia. Ideally I would like to be able to write an analogous code as the below using the GPU:

```
addprocs(4);

a = cell(nworkers())
@sync for (idx, pid) in enumerate(workers())
    @async a[idx] = remotecall_fetch(pid, fun, vargs...)
end
```

I have looked around and I have tried **ArrayFire**, however I haven't been able to find a way to use something similar to @sync @async. I understand that **CUDArt** should be able to do something similar, but it seems not to be ready for Julia 0.5.

Would you please show me how to re-write the example above so that the @async operations are executed on the GPU?

Please notice that my graphic card supports CUDA drivers.

Comment: I feel compelled to warn you that the phrase "would you please suggest me a library" often tends to trigger some (usually unwarranted) nasty knee-jerk close-vote reactions in SO. Probably less so in the Julia community, but still. Just in case you want to rephrase.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou thanks. You may be right, I will rephrase it.

Comment: _I_ know this, and _you_ know this, but ... there's some very trigger-happy fingers out there ...

Comment: btw, have you had a look at https://github.com/JuliaGPU ? (I haven't used it, but my best bet would be on the `GPUArrays` package)

Comment: I haven't looked at **GPUArrays**, I was looking at **CUDAnative**. I will have a look and I'll let you know. If I manage to find a solution myself I'll post it below.